# Need XLST to read XML file results for filemaker

Tags: xml, parsing, xslt, import, filemaker

Not expert in xml Im trying to import a logfile off printer and i need a xlst file
to import it to filemaker but something is wrong

- What are the results i want?
- Under _Version Result=3.05
- Under "autoDischargeComposition"   Result=1
- Under "height"   Result=500.12077
- Under "Widht"    Result=400.22566
- Under "scaleFixedRatio" Result=True
- Under "Height"    Result=56.20050
- Under "Widht"     Result=56.10050

So I Only need the name and the result
What happens now with the xlst file is that it only, gets the

- _Version 3.05
- autoDischargeComposition  1
- and skips the the rest !!!!

this the printer log.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
    <java version="1.6.0_27" class="java.beans.XMLDecoder"> 
    <object class="rip.properties.XmlEdit"> 
    <void property="_VERSION"> 
    <string>3.05</string> 
    </void> 
    <void property="autoDischargeComposition"> 
    <int>1</int> 
    </void>  
    <void property="scale"> 
    <object class="cmn.math.DimDouble"> 
    <void property="height"> 
    <double>500.12077</double> 
    </void> 
    <void property="width"> 
    <double>400.22566</double> 
    </void> 
    </object> 
    </void> 
   <void property="scaleFixedRatio"> 
   <boolean>true</boolean> 
  </void> 
  <void property="scaleRatio"> 
  <object class="cmn.math.DimDouble"> 
  <void property="height"> 
  <double>56.20050</double> 
  </void> 
  <void property="width"> 
  <double>56.10050</double> 
  </void> 
 </object> 
 </void> 
 </object> 
</java>
```

This is the xlst file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">

    <FMPXMLRESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult">
    <ERRORCODE>0</ERRORCODE>
    <PRODUCT BUILD="" NAME="" VERSION=""/>
    <DATABASE DATEFORMAT="" LAYOUT="" NAME="" RECORDS="" TIMEFORMAT=""/>

    <METADATA>
    <FIELD NAME="_VERSION" TYPE="NUMBER" EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT=""/>
    <FIELD NAME="autoDischargeComposition" TYPE="NUMBER" EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT=""/>

    <FIELD NAME="height" TYPE="NUMBER" EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT=""/>
    <FIELD NAME="width" TYPE="NUMBER" EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT=""/>

    <FIELD NAME="scaleRatio" TYPE="NUMBER" EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT=""/>
    <FIELD NAME="height" TYPE="NUMBER" EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT=""/>
    <FIELD NAME="width" TYPE="NUMBER" EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT=""/>

    </METADATA>

    <RESULTSET FOUND="">

    <xsl:for-each select="java/object">
    <ROW MODID="" RECORDID="">
    <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="void[@property='_VERSION']/string"/></DATA></COL>
    <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="void[@property='autoDischargeComposition']/int"/></DATA></COL>

    <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="void[@property='height']/string"/></DATA></COL>
    <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="void[@property='width']/string"/></DATA></COL>

    <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="void[@property='scaleRatio']/string"/></DATA></COL>
    <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="void[@property='height']/string"/></DATA></COL>
    <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="void[@property='width']/string"/></DATA></COL> 

    </ROW>

    </xsl:for-each>

    </RESULTSET>
    </FMPXMLRESULT>

    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

- Any help  would be grateful
  Thanks

WN

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that for your 'height' and 'width' properties, these are nested within other **object** elements within the **void**

```
<void property="scaleRatio">
   <object class="cmn.math.DimDouble">
      <void property="height">
```

However, you doing just `<xsl:value-of select="void[@property='height']/string"/>` to get the value, which will only look for **void** elements within the current **object** element. I think you should probably be doing something like this to cope with the double-nested void.

```
<xsl:value-of 
   select="void[@property='scale']/object/void[@property='height']/double"/>
```

The only other issue you have is you are looking for a string value for your 'scaleRatio' element. I think you possibly need to be using 'scaleFixedRatio' here.

Try the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <FMPXMLRESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult">
         <ERRORCODE>0</ERRORCODE>
         <PRODUCT BUILD="" NAME="" VERSION=""/>
         <DATABASE DATEFORMAT="" LAYOUT="" NAME="" RECORDS="" TIMEFORMAT=""/>
         <METADATA>
            <FIELD NAME="_VERSION" TYPE="NUMBER" EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT=""/>
            <FIELD NAME="autoDischargeComposition" TYPE="NUMBER" EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT=""/>
            <FIELD NAME="height" TYPE="NUMBER" EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT=""/>
            <FIELD NAME="width" TYPE="NUMBER" EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT=""/>
            <FIELD NAME="scaleRatio" TYPE="NUMBER" EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT=""/>
            <FIELD NAME="height" TYPE="NUMBER" EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT=""/>
            <FIELD NAME="width" TYPE="NUMBER" EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT=""/>
         </METADATA>
         <RESULTSET FOUND="">
            <xsl:for-each select="java/object">
               <ROW MODID="" RECORDID="">
                  <COL>
                     <DATA>
                        <xsl:value-of select="void[@property='_VERSION']/string"/>
                     </DATA>
                  </COL>
                  <COL>
                     <DATA>
                        <xsl:value-of select="void[@property='autoDischargeComposition']/int"/>
                     </DATA>
                  </COL>
                  <COL>
                     <DATA>
                        <xsl:value-of select="void[@property='scale']/object/void[@property='height']/double"/>
                     </DATA>
                  </COL>
                  <COL>
                     <DATA>
                        <xsl:value-of select="void[@property='scale']/object/void[@property='width']/double"/>
                     </DATA>
                  </COL>
                  <COL>
                     <DATA>
                        <xsl:value-of select="void[@property='scaleFixedRatio']/boolean"/>
                     </DATA>
                  </COL>
                  <COL>
                     <DATA>
                        <xsl:value-of select="void[@property='scaleRatio']/object/void[@property='height']/double"/>
                     </DATA>
                  </COL>
                  <COL>
                     <DATA>
                        <xsl:value-of select="void[@property='scaleRatio']/object/void[@property='width']/double"/>
                     </DATA>
                  </COL>
               </ROW>
            </xsl:for-each>
         </RESULTSET>
      </FMPXMLRESULT>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your XML, the following is output

```
<FMPXMLRESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult">
   <ERRORCODE>0</ERRORCODE>
   <PRODUCT BUILD="" NAME="" VERSION=""/>
   <DATABASE DATEFORMAT="" LAYOUT="" NAME="" RECORDS="" TIMEFORMAT=""/>
   <METADATA>
      <FIELD NAME="_VERSION" TYPE="NUMBER" EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT=""/>
      <FIELD NAME="autoDischargeComposition" TYPE="NUMBER" EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT=""/>
      <FIELD NAME="height" TYPE="NUMBER" EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT=""/>
      <FIELD NAME="width" TYPE="NUMBER" EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT=""/>
      <FIELD NAME="scaleRatio" TYPE="NUMBER" EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT=""/>
      <FIELD NAME="height" TYPE="NUMBER" EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT=""/>
      <FIELD NAME="width" TYPE="NUMBER" EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT=""/>
   </METADATA>
   <RESULTSET FOUND="">
      <ROW MODID="" RECORDID="">
         <COL>
            <DATA>3.05</DATA>
         </COL>
         <COL>
            <DATA>1</DATA>
         </COL>
         <COL>
            <DATA>500.12077</DATA>
         </COL>
         <COL>
            <DATA>400.22566</DATA>
         </COL>
         <COL>
            <DATA>true</DATA>
         </COL>
         <COL>
            <DATA>56.20050</DATA>
         </COL>
         <COL>
            <DATA>56.10050</DATA>
         </COL>
      </ROW>
   </RESULTSET>
</FMPXMLRESULT>
```